# Create cell in RelativeLayout square

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've RelativeLayout created in `layout/activity.xml`

And i want to add some elements there programmatically by following way:

```
RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 rlayout.addView(CustomView,p);
```

And it works, but elements which were added doesn't fill all view, but i need it.

and also i want to add such elements in square (width=height), how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill all view Use `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` instead of `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`.
To make layout as square just create `int width,height = 300;` and then :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
```

or pass `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` into `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and change height and width of your custom view.

To make view square :

```
    Button customView = new Button(this);
    customView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));

    RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1); 
    rlayout.addView(customView);
```

to make fill on all view you can use this:

```
    Button customView = new Button(this);
    customView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1); 
    rlayout.addView(customView);
```

Also you can add rules for your layout items like this :

```
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

Best wishes.